# httplib2 on twisted way

Tags: python, twisted

How can I convert the httplib2 part to a "twisted" way?

```
from twisted.python import log, usage
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort
from twisted.web.client import Agent

from struct import unpack

import httplib2

import sys

class JamesOptions(usage.Options):
    optParameters = [
        ['outfile', 'o', None, 'Logfile [default: sys.stdout]'],
        ['baudrate', 'b', 38400, 'Serial baudrate [default: 9600'],
        ['port', 'p', '/dev/tty.usbserial-A600ezgH', 'Serial Port device'],
    ]

class XbeeLogger:
    def decodeFloat(self, var):
        text = ""
        for i in range(0, len(var)):
            text += var[i]
        return unpack('f', text)[0]

    def handle_packet(self, *args):
        response = self._split_response(args)
        h = httplib2.Http()
        resp, content = h.request(
            "http://localhost/emoncms2/api/post?apikey=2c0915af95786b73d841da00da68b5fa&json={real_power:" + 
            str(decodeFloat(response.get("rf_data")[0:4])) + 
            ",apparent_power:" + 
            str(decodeFloat(response.get("rf_data")[4:8])) + 
            ",power_factory:" + 
            str(decodeFloat(response.get("rf_data")[8:12])) + 
            ",vrms:" + 
            str(decodeFloat(response.get("rf_data")[12:16])) + 
            ",irms:" + 
            str(decodeFloat(response.get("rf_data")[16:20])) + 
            "}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = JamesOptions()
    try:
        o.parseOptions()
    except usage.UsageError, errortext:
        print '%s: %s' % (sys.argv[0], errortext)
        print '%s: Try --help for usage details.' % (sys.argv[0])
        raise SystemExit, 1

    logFile = o.opts['outfile']
    if logFile is None:
        logFile = sys.stdout
    log.startLogging(logFile)

    from xbeeService.protocol import ZigBeeProtocol
    class XbeeTest(ZigBeeProtocol, XbeeLogger):
        pass

    port = o.opts['port']
    log.msg('Attempting to open %s at %dbps as a %s device' % (port, o.opts['baudrate'], ZigBeeProtocol.__name__))
    s = SerialPort(XbeeTest(), o.opts['port'], reactor, baudrate=o.opts['baudrate'])
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: I would have been looking at a solution, but seeing a line of 441 chars made my... argh! Please refactor your code before posting (noting that this is the only line at which we should look at)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`twisted.web.client.Agent().request()`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html#request). It will return a [`Deferred`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html).

See the [Agent howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html#auto2) for more details and examples.